# Linux shell script: Allow user to provide variable names in input prompt

Tags: shell-script

I'm writing a shell-script for linux terminal. I want to be able to input variable names on a prompt. For example:

**test.sh:**

```
 test="Monkey in the middle..."
 read -p "Enter input: " input
 echo $input
```

**output:**

```
 Enter input: $test
 $test
```

I want to be able to input "$test" during the `read -p` prompt segment of the script and have the script echo "Monkey in the middle..." at the end instead of echo-ing "$test" as it does now.

How would I go about doing that?

---

---

**UPDATE:**

Using the answers provided to me here and in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400137/linux-shell-script-allow-user-to-use-variables-in-input) (a big thanks to the contributors and commentators!), I managed to piece together this line which worked very well for me:

```
newvariable="$(eval echo $input)"
```

Be, advised, I was warned more than once that using eval may pose a security risk. Keep that in mind if you opt for this solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
echo "$input"
```

try

```
eval echo "$input"
```

It's not even bash-specific, works on /bin/sh!

Note that this poses a serious security risk because `eval` just executes what you give it.  In this case, the shell interprets the string `$input` as `$test`, and then `eval` executes `echo $test`.  But what if the user entered `$test; rm -rf *`?  `eval` would be presented with `echo $test; rm -rf *`.  Be very careful if you do this.

Comment: Yes, this works!

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked for me too. How would I go about saving the output of eval echo $input as new variable?

Comment: I found it, newvariable="$(eval echo $input)" will save the output of eval echo $input to newvariable.

Comment: Combining $test with other strings is resulting in the error messages  "unexpected EOF while looking for matching `'' and "syntax error: unexpected end of file". Any idea what could be causing that. For example, I tried to input: You've always been a $test which I  was hoping would make You've always been a monkey in the middle

Comment: It turns out the ' character I was using in the word "You've" at the begining of my test string was causing the EOF.

Comment: Here's a solution.  After you read in $input, do `input=$(echo $input | sed "s/\'/\\\'/g" | sed 's/\"/\\\"/g')`.  After that, just use your eval expression as before.

Answer (score 2):

In bash you can use an [indirect parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#indirection) syntax:

```
test="Monkey in the middle..."
read -p "Enter input: " input
echo ${!input}
```

In this case user has to provide `test` string only without preceding dollar sign.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't mind that the user can execute arbitrary commands by including a command substitution `$(…)`, you can submit the string to the `eval` builtin. Note that `eval` expects a shell snippet, and if the input includes quotes, they may cause syntax errors. The (relatively) easy way to cope with quotes is to use a here document to perform the substitutions. You're still at the mercy of an unterminated variable or command substitution (e.g. `$(foo`).

```
IFS= read -r -p "Enter input: " input
eval "string=\$(cat <<EOF
_${input}
EOF
)"
string=${string#_}
```